# Push Multiple Values into mongodb array using nodeJS

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have one mongodb schema (ChampionshipSchema) that accepts a multiple values :

```
tieBreak: [{
  name: String,
  priority : Number
}],
```

If I add one by one in this schema, it is OK, but if I try to add a list do values at the same time, I have an error.

Code to add in the schema :

```
function createTable (idChampionship, tieBreaks, callback) {
  // tieBreaks is an array of tieBreak values
  var query = { _id : idChampionship };

  var newValues = {
    $push: { tieBreak: tieBreaks }
  };

  Championship
    .update(query, newValues)
    .exec((err, result) => {
      if(err) callback (false);
      else {
        if (result.nModified > 0) {
          callback(true);
        } else {
          callback(false);
        }
      }
    });
}
```

And the result is :

```
"tieBreak": [[{
  "_id": ObjectId("5ac61f8002e836a14c4ab2b1"),
  "name": "wins"
},
{
  "_id": ObjectId("5ac61f8002e836a14c4ab2b0"),
  "name": "balance"
}]]
```

This means that this function added a List of TieBreaks inside one tieBreak document, but my intention is to add a list of TieBreaks and each value of that list fill just one document, the return should me like this:

```
"tieBreak": [{
  "_id": ObjectId("5ac61f8002e836a14c4ab2b1"),
  "name": "wins"
},
{
  "_id": ObjectId("5ac61f8002e836a14c4ab2b0"),
  "name": "balance"
}]
```

How can I do it?

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
function createTable (idChampionship, tieBreaks, callback) {
  const query = { _id : idChampionship };

  // assuming tieBreaks is an array. without $each, mongoose just pushes the array as is.
  const newValues = {
    $addToSet: { tieBreak: {$each: tieBreaks } }
  };

  Championship
    .updateOne(query, newValues)
    .exec((err, result) => {
      if(err) { 
          callback(false);
      } else {
          callback(result.nModified > 0);
      }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Currently, you can do it as follows:

```js
const filter = { _id : idChampionship }
const update = { $push: { tieBreak: { $each: tieBreaks }}}
Championship.updateOne(filter, update)
```

Answer (score -2):

I think that the best way is do it step by step. For example:

1- Get championship
2- forEach tieBreak, push in championship
3- Save.

=)